# Low sound volume with headphones

Tags: 18.04, sound

I have a dual boot ubuntu 18.04/windows 10 on my PC. On windows 10 the sound works fine whether it's coming from my headphones or the speaker of the laptop. In ubuntu, the sound is fine when it's coming from the speaker of the laptop, but very low when it's coming from the headphones.
Any idea on why this could happend and how to fix it?

Comment: Tweaking things up in `alsamixer` didn't help for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research, I launched alsamixer, and there my `Headphone` was at 100 and my `Speaker` at 0, I put the `Speaker` at 100, and my volume is now at a normal volume in my Headphones.